# Can't access Oracle Cloud Always Free Compute http port

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-18.04, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Yesterday, I was set up my first always free compute VM. I installed ubuntu 18.04 minimal on my VM. For my web service need, I installed Nginx. I'm confused because when I tried to access my public IP via a web browser, the Nginx welcome page didn't load. I think that is because port 80 didn't open. So, I tried to open that with set Ingress Rules in Security List Details menu as the picture below.
[Ingress Rule for port 80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHid4.png)

But now, I still can't access the web server in my VM. May be there more experienced people in Oracle Cloud who can help me to solve this. Thank you

Comment: Do nginx started? Can you see access.log?

Comment: yes Nginx started and the error log is empty

Comment: In my case the Oracle maintenance caused a reboot, that did reset my custom port; and I don't know how to save the changes to prevent that  (`chkconfig iptables on` requires a password I do not have)‍♂️. – I had to re-open the port via `sudo iptables -I INPUT 5 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT  -m comment --comment "CUSTOM: allow ingress (see OracleCloud SecurityList for instance's subnet), for Nginx"`.

Answer (score 187):

I wasted a lot of time on this.
I wish I had found this first:
https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/developer-tutorials/tutorials/apache-on-ubuntu/01oci-ubuntu-apache-summary.htm

1. configure ingress route for port 80
2. install ubuntu.
3. install apache/nginx
4. `curl localhost` should bring back webpage in text format, however fails over internet.
5. forget ufw firewall - this may cause issues with the Oracle firewall
6. use

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT 6 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo netfilter-persistent save
```

7. test your web page over internet

Comment: Great point! I used ufw and it never worked and wasted a ton of time.

Comment: step 6 saved me! Did some docs-digging and for anyone curious about iptables command: "INPUT" is a "table/chain" of packet filtering rules for incoming packets. "-I" and "6" insert a new rule in the 6th slot in this table, which currently has a global reject rule for anything other than SSH and a few other things. "-m state --state NEW" matches for new connections. "-p tcp" matches the TCP protocols. "--dport 80" matches for a destination port of 80 (HTTP). And "-j ACCEPT" means "jump" straight to the action of accepting the packet

Comment: Thank you. I had been breaking my head over this since yesterday. It's now up and running.

Comment: It has solved my problem in ubuntu 20.04(Canonical-Ubuntu-20.04-Minimal-2021.06.14-0) installed on oracle cloud instance. `ufw` might cause the problem. I have disabled and uninstall ufw and step 6 has make port 80 nginx availabe on internet.

Comment: @JohnC This finally solved my issue!! I thought I disabled the local firewall though. Any idea why `sudo ufw disable` wouldn't work?

Comment: I had followed the official docs from Oracle but they didn't mention the `ufw` part. Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to use this but my ubuntu returns: iptables: Index of insertion too big.

Comment: thanks, it really worked.
i have been contacting OCI support for 3 days but they didn't help

Comment: Thanks for this! iptable works! There are default INPUT and OUTPUT limits in place for Oracle Cloud.

Comment: the fastest route to open ports from the dashboard is: `Networking >    Virtual Cloud Networks >    vcn-20221234-1234 >    Security List Details`

Comment: still not working for me

Comment: Worked for me as of 2022-08-24.

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/enabling-network-traffic-to-ubuntu-images-in-oracle-cloud-infrastructure according to this doc page under Host Firewall, ufw is problematic with Oracle dont use it with OC

Comment: Thank you sir for this solution. Was stuck on this since yesterday and it now finally works! Throwing in some keywords for anybody else facing this issue in future - Oracle OCI Nginx HTTP 80 port localhost works internet not accessible

Comment: it worked without adding the -6 flag, thanks

Comment: 2024, March: #6 Saved me! As a Linux rookie I'm terrified of iptables (once I made it so I couldn't even access SSH :d ) and I don't know why I needed it now? It was working perfectly but I ran a site (this is my dev server) that hogged the memory and had to reboot forcedfully.. and then no HTTP (everything else was fine). I thought it was excess of consumption? Very weird.

Answer (score 51):

This is how I did it without directly meddling with `iptables`.

First create an `Ingress Rule` in Oracle Cloud vps's dashboard/Networking/Virtual Cloud Networks, for example, for port range 23-90
[image: Ingress Rule port range 23-90]

Next, install `firewalld` in ubuntu (`firewalld` is available in centos I think)

```
sudo apt-get install firewalld
sudo systemctl enable firewalld
sudo systemctl start firewalld
```

You only need to do this one time. It will still be there after a reboot.

Then, to open port 80:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent  #  or --add-service=http 
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

To verify:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
```

Output:

```
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 80/tcp
  ...
```

The same applies to opening other port(s). You can easily remove the port (`--remove-port=80/tcp` + a `--reload`), refer to `firewalld` docs.

To test from a remote computer

1. run a web server at port 80 in Oracle Cloud vps if one is not already running, for example:

   ```sh
   python3 -m http.server 80
   ```
2. In a remote computer

   ```sh
   curl ip-of-oc-vps:80
   ```

I also wasted a lot of time on Oracle Cloud Always Free vps' firewall. I hope this can save other people some time.

Comment: To locate Ingress Rules (rather obscure I'd say, took me a while even for my second run after a while. I detailed it here for future reference): from Oracle Cloud vps's dashboard/Networking/Virtual Cloud Networks/, click the name of NCN (e.g. VirtualCloudNetwork-2019), click Security Lists, click the name of a list (e.g. Default Security List for VirtualCloudNetwork-2019). Two Ingress Rules will be shown. (The default Ingress Rules are very strict.) These can be modified.

Comment: I followed these instructions on an "almost-free" Oracle ARM instance running Ubuntu 20.04.3. `sudo apt-get install firewalld` enables and starts `firewalld`, no need for telling `systemctl` to do so. OTOH I could enable HTTP(S) only with the "long commands", e.g. `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent`, the short `sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=http` didn't seem to have an effect. YMMV of course.

Comment: Okay this actually works for me, i don't know how important the `--reload` part is, but the `--permanent` part is actually important, otherwise it won't shown on `--list-all`. Also making thing a bit clearer, the interchangeable part is the `--add-port` with `--add-service` part

Comment: WARNING: if you have docker installed before firewalld, **it will break Docker's networking**. You have to re-install docker after firewalld to have the networking configured for firewalld.

Comment: ANOTHER WARNING: After I updated my Ubuntu 20.04 instance on OCI to 22.04, `firewalld` stopped without a warning. Had to enable/start it again. Also had to restart Docker.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT 6 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

$ sudo iptables -I INPUT 6 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

$ sudo netfilter-persistent save
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to allow Firewall for the port you want

Suppose you want the HTTP and HTTPS ports on your instance up, then following commands would suffice.

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Then save the iptable rules even after reboot next time by

```
sudo service iptables save
```

Also make sure you have kept the ingress rules for the ports on Oracle Cloud console.

Comment: Thanks working fine, after given following command
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Internet Gateway and Route Table is also configured, you might still need to check the OS level firewall. If that is not configured, you might need to execute this command: 
`sudo ufw allow http`
For more details please see: [How to Open/Allow incoming firewall port on Ubuntu](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-open-allow-incoming-firewall-port-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

Comment: After I configure ufw as tutorial above, port 80 still closed

Comment: Have you added Internet Gateway to the VCN and Route Table Rule to the subnet for the specific traffic?

Answer (score 1):

In my case - CentOS 8 Image, firewall-cmd saved rules, but the ports didn't work. The reason is that the system uses iptables and not nftables. So, change this /etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf file

```
# FirewallBackend=nftables
FirewallBackend=iptables
```

and

```
#firewall-cmd restart
```

did the trick.

Comment: to clarify: nftables did partially work, but I suppose it didn't create states, I could tcpdump ingress traffic after opening the port, but absolutely no egress and netcat couldn't establish the connection