# Can not reach open ports on Oracle Cloud Instance

Tags: ubuntu, portforwarding, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, firewalld

I have 2 micro instances running in Oracle Cloud, both under the same subnet with some port forwarding enabled, namely

[image]

On the first instance I enabled also these ports in `firewalld` and I'm able to reach them from outside.

```
ubuntu@instance:~$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 80/tcp 443/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

```
user@iMac:~$ telnet instance_ip 443
Trying ...
Connected to instance_ip.
```

I did exactly the same thing on the second instance, which means that `sudo firewall-cmd --list-all` returns the same ouput. A quick check with `sudo iptables -S` also shows the same result.
As both instances are connected to the same subnet I would expect the port forwarding to work in the same way. However, I can only connect to port 22 on the second instance. Any attempt to ping other ports results in a `Connection refused`.

What am I forgetting?

P.S. I'm aware of question [Can't access Oracle Cloud Always Free Compute http port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62326988/cant-access-oracle-cloud-always-free-compute-http-port). Obviously I already followed every suggestion in that question, but that helped in setting up only the first instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a firewall is in place, the connection is not refused but blocked ("Connection Time Out"). So if you get a "Connection refused.", this sounds more like no process is running on the host listening on the port. Can you check with "netstat -na | grep LISTEN" if a process is listening on port 80/443 ?

Comment: You were totally right, I didn't consider the difference!